# Rails - Radio button change image based on checked, hover and focus

Tags: javascript

I have a label with an image and a checkbox. I want to change the image based on hover in/out and checkbox status.

I have several radio buttons, and two images for each : "image-active" and "image-inactive".

I want to show the "active" image when the button is checked or the label is  hovered, and the inactive one when the button is not checked and the label is not hovered. I figured the best way was to pass the image sources as data-attribute and to play with some JS, but I'm not really sure and the code I'm coming up with seems quite complex.

```
<label>
  <img data-active-image="xxx", data-inactive-image="...">
  <input type="radio">
</label>
```

The code is generated from a Rails app, but I don't think it matters here. Only thing to keep in mind, is that the data-active-image stuff is dynamic and handled by the backend, so I don't really want use CSS styles / background tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably far easier with CSS than with JS.

```
<label>
  <input type="radio">
  <img class="active" src="active_img_src">
  <img class="inactive" src="inactive_img_src">
</label>

label input:checked ~ img.inactive,
label:hover input:not(:checked) ~ img.inactive {
  display:none;
}

label input:not(:checked) ~ img.active,
label:hover input:checked ~ img.active {
  display:none;
}

label:hover input:checked ~ img.inactive,
label:hover input:not(:checked) ~ img.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Oh my... why did I not think of adding both <img> tags before :'(. Will try that in a moment, in the meantime I'll post my JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

My fat JS solution

```
$('.mylabel').hover(function(){
    var image = $(this).find("img")
    image.attr("src", image.data('active-image'));
}, function() {
    activeIfChecked(
        $(this).find("img"),
        $(this).find("input")
    )
} )

$('.mylabel').on('click', function () {
    $('.gender-label').each(function (){
        activeIfChecked(
            $(this).find("img"),
            $(this).find("input")
        )
    })
})

function activeIfChecked(image, checkbox){
    if(checkbox.prop('checked')) {
            image.attr("src", image.data('active-image'));
        } else {
            image.attr("src", image.data('inactive-image'));
        }
    }
```